# Matplotlib - Setting transparency with alpha - Float is required ERROR

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a relatively simple line graph in matplotlib. I would also line to use the fill_between function to show the range on my dataset. All goes well until I try to change the line width or transparency, at which point I get an error message about a float being required. Details below, help appreciated!

Here is the code that works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# set y axis data
GDP = np.array([7.639597855, 0.668364743, -1.391078517, 2.661103268, 13.616493420, 13.249036323, 7.281549943, -1.923079168, 5.882359893, 0.479297978, 16.218563633, 6.231349008, 2.300661571, 7.175963618, 6.086823810, 4.997731243, 4.918031369, 9.745068027, 4.396153740, 0.406746413, -5.290119219, 2.503453814, 3.718709051, 5.360304094, 4.570982302, -0.214802518, 1.625239182, 3.177291278, 1.344689707, 5.692294494, 8.730231829, -7.332978135, 9.691840268, -10.240181734, 16.728817592, 7.316681511, 3.792419099, 3.895253630, 3.042278091, 1.576077837, -4.974963846, 1.700000014, 5.705639437, 5.420497694, 3.268725828, 4.699999992, 9.600000003, 7.639736774, 8.328110276, 6.874065635, 4.854055109, 1.885799507, 5.199999998, 5.700000004]) 

CRU = np.array([17.755142679, 19.335497440, 21.622335826, -12.073797213, 3.999034506, -9.475694888, 10.355172968, 4.996985354, 1.033423493, 2.963522079, -0.415849338, -2.371187899, -8.482201424, 21.195837288, -8.959330850, 8.838202418, -0.650467109, 24.043806858, 13.676769994, 6.762785969, -6.701641029, 9.332788410, -14.124247766, 8.463198792, 10.652162335, 12.791879945, -20.228329466, 2.432194747, 26.307600326, -19.982628632, -0.130897935, -28.908753912, -9.026400028, -19.159674318, -13.110411784, 1.944700332, 12.290065083, -16.108325638, 7.026359593, 2.601995038, 5.296270660, -7.966607112, -5.523790280, 10.172303461, -26.469221663, -7.533055761, -0.945520221, -3.812963741, -1.797739574, -17.746473033, 8.188227076, -7.879891920, -2.228654668, 0.293175902])

UDEL = np.array([11.899523323, 17.861516803, 16.553853336, -13.532223779, 2.045308385, -12.223353436, 5.594526040, 0.697061858, -1.968696531, -2.892204603, -7.240865286, -3.746098020, -9.450137601, 21.223088126, -9.144701377, 6.646804560, -3.066178302, 18.978504248, 8.173074770, 5.410066043, -9.041538341, 10.123093224, -11.095691087, 7.718620646, 9.593480943, 10.896080250, -19.495512814, 1.509412450, 24.902527231, -17.629768130, 3.145800348, -25.714543461, -7.128283306, -7.123569844, -7.243745583, 6.369015183, 0.706585730, -11.363145013, 17.397897956, -4.310273542, -0.527486427, 10.208495822, -5.064073728, -1.329337813, -22.774365218, -10.505280708, -2.111652862, -12.582987433, -3.490887130, -10.280867587, -7.472680751, -8.090879326, -6.781710803, -6.840851782])

GPCC = np.array([16.96440077, 21.31853596, 21.18164748, -13.60591879, 3.55704089, -8.39523610, 8.80772681, 2.39764723, 1.11760902, -1.88245560, -4.07633303, -4.62352382, -10.10198418, 19.68417671, -10.39260873, 8.66522599, -3.10826388, 19.50580777, 9.52955687, 5.83543665, -12.81421018, 9.23118153, -13.92843771, 6.28127782, 7.70194150, 12.95661985, -20.89661581, 1.34328436, 27.65706334, -17.07632076, 0.20551831, -24.02615780, -3.85592627, -14.28557029, -12.99754482, 4.50965431, 18.06356323, -11.61684001, 6.50140262, 6.12862642, 3.21197607, -1.39281474, -6.48847559, 9.60057444, -19.79702678, 7.49589034, 1.96623672, 2.24351173, -0.03860793, -9.80248538, 1.86693760, -8.04271946, -7.32827264, -3.05899477])

AVE_PR = np.array([15.539688924, 19.505183399, 19.785945546, -13.070646593, 3.200461259, -10.031428142, 8.252475273, 2.697231479, 0.060778662, -0.603712707, -3.911015886, -3.580269912, -9.344774402, 20.701034041, -9.498880318, 8.050077656, -2.274969763, 20.842706293, 10.459800544, 6.002762887, -9.519129850, 9.562354387, -13.049458855, 7.487699087, 9.315861593, 12.214860015, -20.206819362, 1.761630519, 26.289063634, -18.229572508, 1.073473574, -26.216485056, -6.670203203, -13.522938150, -11.117234061, 4.274456607, 10.353404682, -13.029436887, 10.308553391, 1.473449306, 2.660253435, 0.283024655, -5.692113199, 6.147846697, -23.013537888, -3.514148708, -0.363645454, -4.717479816, -1.775744876, -12.609941999, 0.860827975, -8.004496903, -5.446212705, -3.202223551])


# set x axis
X = np.array([1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014])


# assign the line colours and set x axis to 'year' rather than 'time'
plt.plot(X, CRU, color='blue')   
plt.plot(X, UDEL, color='blue')
plt.plot(X, GPCC, color='blue')
plt.fill_between(X, CRU, UDEL, color='blue')
plt.fill_between(X, GPCC, UDEL, color='blue')
plt.fill_between(X, GPCC, CRU, color='blue')
plt.plot(X, AVE_PR, label='Annual Change in Precipitation from 1971-2000 Average', lw=3, color='blue')
plt.plot(X, GDP, label='Annual GDP Growth', lw=3, color='black')

#set a title for the y axis
plt.ylabel('Percentage (%)')

#create a legend and set its location to under the graph
plt.legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), fancybox=True, shadow=True)

#add grid lines
plt.grid()

#show the graph in the console
plt.show()
```

This outputs this image:
[image]

However, if I try to change the line width or transparency of the lines, I get an error. I am changing it as follows:

```
plt.plot(X, CRU, color='blue', lw=1, alpha='0.5')   
plt.plot(X, UDEL, color='blue', lw=1, alpha='0.5')   
plt.plot(X, GPCC, color='blue', lw=1, alpha='0.5')   
plt.fill_between(X, CRU, UDEL, color='blue', alpha='0.5') 
plt.fill_between(X, GPCC, UDEL, color='blue', alpha='0.5') 
plt.fill_between(X, GPCC, CRU, color='blue', alpha='0.5') 
plt.plot(X, AVE_PR, label='Annual Change in Precipitation from 1971-2000 Average', lw=3, color='blue')
plt.plot(X, GDP, label='Annual GDP Growth', lw=3, color='black')
```

I then get the following error:

```
    File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 334, in __call__
    return printer(obj)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py", line 240, in <lambda>
    png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py", line 124, in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2180, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 527, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
    func(*args)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2319, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 771, in draw
    drawFunc(renderer, gc, tpath, affine.frozen())

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1209, in _draw_lines
    self._lineFunc(renderer, gc, path, trans)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1234, in _draw_solid
    renderer.draw_path(gc, path, trans)

  File "/scratch/s0899345/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 166, in draw_path
    self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)

TypeError: a float is required

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f8f0cc0cc10>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 alpha='0.5'
```

by

```
 alpha=0.5
```

in all your six `plt.fill_between`  and `plt.plot` commands. The transparency `alpha` has to be a float. You are using a string and hence you are getting the error `a float is required`. More information on [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) official page where the Description of each argument is provided.

Comment: sigh, so simple. Sorry I missed it. Thank you!!

Comment: @Bazingaa I'll offset it for you to keep balance in the universe

Comment: Lolz, you ought to start writing some good Sci-Fi literature ;)